# Programming Split two words from a phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help. I am new in the SQL
I need to separate row word in two. This with a code SQL server

```
(2 rows value and work)
VALUE    WORK
0        TODAY_17_05_2013   CONTROL MACHINE
1        TODAY_17_06_2013   CONTROL SOFTWRE       
2        TODAY_17_07_2013   CONTROL HARDAWRE
```

and obtaine 3 tables.
There are 3 spaces betwen `TODAY_17_05_2013` and `CONTROL MACHINE`

```
(1 TABLE)
VALUE
0
1                    
2   

(2 TABLE)
WORD
TODAY_17_05_2013
TODAY_17_06_2013
TODAY_17_07_2013  

(3 table)-->> create table with description
Description
CONTROL MACHINE
CONTROL HARDAWRE
CONTROL SOFTWRE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following queries:

```
select value
into tValue
from t;

select left(work, charindex('   ', work) - 1) as word
into tWord
from t;

select substring(work, charindex('   ', work) + 3, len(work)) as description
into tDescription
from t;
```

Why would you putting these into three separate tables, rather than one table with three columns?  Is this some sort of homework assignment?